# Using Koalas, how do I save to an external table?

Tags: pyspark-pandas, spark-koalas

I have the code below to save a Koalas dataframe to an Orc table. How to modify it to save to an EXTERNAL table?

```
df.reset_index().to_orc(
    f"/corporativo/mydatabase/mytable",
    mode="overwrite",
    partition_cols=["year", "month"]
)
```